# How can I store current user session and retrive it later in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, session-cookies

I am trying to store current session for user's activity and then try to restore it once user login later. I am developing site, where user is going to answer 100 questions, and I am sure user won't answer in one go. So, how can I manage this one? Should I store answers and retrieve it later or I can store session id, and can do something.

Comment: You need to learn more Asp.net sessions

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808915/asp-net-retaining-the-old-browser-session-after-closing-and-reopening-browser-i/17809180#17809180

Comment: You can not do that with session, you need to store some where else your data for your user and connect to it with the cookie of it.